# Why does SQLite not use an index when using a literal column value in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sqlite

Here's the [sqlfiddle of my example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d00d1/7/0), but let me explain:

When I have a simple table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
    (`id` int, `productName` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55))
;
```

And a simple index on the `productName` column like this:

```
CREATE INDEX test_idx ON ForgeRock(productName);
```

I can easily select data using the `productName` in the WHERE clause and my index is being used. Nice.

When I add a hard-coded value to the list of columns I'm selecting, it also works well and the index is used, too:

```
SELECT
  0 as foo,
  0 as bar,
  productName,
  description
FROM
  ForgeRock
WHERE (foo = 0 AND productName IN ('OpenIDM', 'OpenDJ'))
```

Even using the hard-coded `foo` column in the WHERE clause still uses the index (as it should). But here's my question: Why is the index NOT being used when I add `OR (foo = 1 AND bar IN (1))` to the WHERE clause?

```
SELECT
  0 as foo,
  0 as bar,
  productName,
  description
FROM
  ForgeRock
WHERE (foo = 0 AND productName IN ('OpenIDM', 'OpenDJ')) OR (foo = 1 AND bar IN (1));
```

Any help would be appreciated. Once again, [here's the sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d00d1/7).

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#or_opt) says:

> WHERE clause constraints that are connected by OR instead of AND can be handled [...]
>   For any given query, the fact that the OR-clause optimization described here can be used does not guarantee that it will be used. SQLite uses a cost-based query planner that estimates the CPU and disk I/O costs of various competing query plans and chooses the plan that it thinks will be the fastest. If there are many OR terms in the WHERE clause or if some of the indices on individual OR-clause subterms are not very selective, then SQLite might decide that it is faster to use a different query algorithm, or even a full-table scan.